# How to Do Efficient JOIN on multiple table in MySQL or SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am struggling to join multiple table in mySQL or SQL Server and keep the performance fast. 
I have this table:

table songs

```
songID|songName
---------------
01|diamond
02|goodbye
```

table singersong

```
 songID|singerID
 ---------------
 01|15
 02|22
```

table singers

```
singerID|singerName|Sex
------------------------
15| Rihanna | F
22| Air Supply | M
```

And I want my result like this:

```
songID|songName|singerName|Sex
------------------------------ 
01|diamond|Rihanna|F 
02|goodbye|Air Supply| M
```

My Query is like this

```
SELECT s.songID, s.songName, sr.singerName, sr.Sex 
FROM songs s, singersong ss, singer sr
WHERE 
ss.songID = s.songID AND 
ss.singerID = sr.singerID
ORDER BY s.songID
```

And it's performing very very slow.. is there anyway to make this query simpler or more efficient ?

Thanks very much for the help..
LL

Comment: Assume there is a singer who does not have corresponding song. Do you want him as well to be included in the result?

Comment: @JSWorld No I don't want that.. It will be based on song first then look up the singer detail.. so if there is song but no singer it will be okay but not the other way around. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the conditions to join on. Your current query, depending upon the whims of the optimiser, may be producing a cartesian product between all tables and then filtering the result. Also make sure you have indexes and FKs setup properly.

```
SELECT s.songID, s.songName, sr.singerName, sr.Sex 
FROM songs s
LEFT JOIN singersong ss ON s.songID = ss.songID
LEFT JOIN singer sr ON ss.singerID = sr.singerID
ORDER BY s.songID
```

Replace `LEFT JOIN` with `INNER JOIN` if you do not want null values returned when there are no matching entries in a related table.

Comment: Should be INNER JOIN, not LEFT JOIN, to be equivalent to his original.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is not the modern style, but it should work fine. For performance, make sure you have indexes on all the columns used for the join: `songID` and `singerID`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not enough just have indexes, you need multi-column index that spans the join table in the direction of travel, i.e if you are starting from Song and going to Singer the index would be:
   INDEX songSinger (songID,singerID)

And if you were querying from Singer to Song, the index would be:
   INDEX SingerSong (singerID,songID)

If you only have one column indexed, then MySQL will use the index to get the set of results from table singersong, load the results and then scan down that list of results for the next step of the join.

However, If you have an index that spans two columns, MySQL doesn't even load the join table, it just uses the index.